# url php multi method get using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

if i have a url like:

```
domain.com/profile.php?id=1&lang=en
```

Can i get a url like this using htaccess?

```
domain.com/1/en
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do it in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/1/en$ /profile.php?id=1&lang=en
```